# Where is the Queen placed when a C/M is already at center?

Tags: carrom

If a player pockets the Queen, but doesn't cover it, while there is a C/M in the center of the board, should the C/M be moved from the center to place the Queen or should the Queen be placed next to the C/M on the opposite side to the player?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Laws of Carrom](http://www.carrom.co.uk/laws-of-carrom/#XV) **94**

> If the Centre Circle is partially or completely covered by other C/M, the Queen shall be placed so as to occupy most of the uncovered portion or in any position adjacent to the Centre Circle in such a way so that it is not easy to pocket for the player having his turn. The placing of the Queen by the Umpire, in such a situation, shall be final.